# Issue with Parameters.AddWithValue and looping through DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable that looks like this:

```
[0]    [1]
"Z12"  "Company A"
"A32"  "Company B"
"K54"  "Company C"
```

I'm trying to loop through the rows, and add them to an Access table with the following code:

```
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\myDB.accdb");

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

cmd.Connection = myConnection;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

myConnection.Open();

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO xCARRIER (CARRIER_ID, CARRIER_NAME) VALUES (@p1, @p2)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

myConnection.Close();
```

When I go into Access and look at the xCARRIER table, it looks like this:

```
"Z12"  "Company A"
"Z12"  "Company A"
"Z12"  "Company A"
```

When I step through the code, it looks like it's looping through the DataTable properly. I'm not sure why it's adding the first row 3 times, though. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either clear your Command parameters after each iteration:

```
 command.Parameters.Clear();
```

So your code would look like this:

```
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\myDB.accdb");

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

cmd.Connection = myConnection;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

myConnection.Open();

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO xCARRIER (CARRIER_ID, CARRIER_NAME) VALUES (@p1, @p2)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

myConnection.Close();
```

Or simply update the previous parameters values:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO xCARRIER (CARRIER_ID, CARRIER_NAME) VALUES (@p1, @p2)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue["@p1"] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue["@p2"] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: That did it. I added it immediately after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`. Thank you!